# Using application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions instead of application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Tags: ios, objective-c

I see Apple in default template use `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`: to setup window in appDelegate class. My question is why don't use `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions` instead. Are there something which can only be done in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Can I use `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to initialize rootViewController.

I still new in IOS, I can understand this might be a stupid question, but any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions***:

*Tells the delegate that the launch process has begun but that state restoration has not yet occurred.*

Vs

***application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions***:

*Tells the delegate that the launch process is almost done and the app is almost ready to run.*

So the difference is clearly visible.
For details you can follow [UIApplicationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)

So *application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions* is just the very previous event of *application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions*

So after having the event *application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions*, the next event *application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions* will be fired.

So it will definitely depend on you needs but usually both are almost similar and most of the time you may not need to use both of those.

So in usual case you can use *application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions* as its the latest event in the similar category.

Comment: that I understand, but can I use 'application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions' to initialize stuff live UINavigationController. If yes, then is it good practice.

Comment: In this case you should use application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions as if you use application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions then the application not yet have launched. UI jobs should be done afterwards.

Comment: What about Frameworks initializations like Parse or Google Analytics?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei You may follow https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/ for google analytics. But I am not sure about 'Parse'.

Comment: One thing to notice is that, during CoreData migration, application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions has the old version, then update step is performed, so that application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions has updated CoreData version.

Comment: you stated the obvious (from the docs, thanks) but not the difference and consequences. Specifically - is it OK or not to initialise viewControllers at the earlier event). My guess (not knowledge) is you should NOT initialise UI on the earlier - because state has NOT been restored, and so you don't know WHAT UI to initialise and present.

Answer (score 1):

The docs helpfully dug by @itsazzad tell us that the time between these two events is used to "*restore app state*".

So it seems pointless to initialise view controllers at the earlier event - because state has not been yet restored - and you don't know which UI to present.

You may be re-launched after kill, and need to immediately skip to mid-work UI scenario.

So my answer is: only initialise UI view controllers on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Comment: Funny you answered this two weeks ago. Last week I posted a very related question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55550755/is-ios-state-restoration-possible-in-ios-library-could-not-find-a-storyboard In my case, I needed to start a framework with its own storyboard when the application launches. So to be "restorable", I now invoke the framework and assign the root view controller in application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions, and it works well. The problem is that iOS can't find the framework's bundle during restoration of the storyboard/view controllers. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I got to mess with this difference for a completely different matter - I register my MacOS to receive AppleEvents from other Apps (and from LaunchServices, as soon as I'm launched, like the "Open Document" or "Quit" appleEvents) and I was missing events because I only registered at "didFinishLaunching"... anyway I think you should postpone your Framework's UI to AFTER the didFinishLaunching. Initialize other things earlier. Not the UI.

Answer (score 0):

In other words willfinishlaunchingwithoptions is exclusive to restoration, while didfinishlaunchingwithoptions is when the whole process is complete.